# Why am I getting a "Mutating arrays is not supported" error here?

Tags: julia, flux.jl

Here's a minimal working example.

```
using Flux

myvector = []
for i in 1:3
    push!(myvector, 0.1 * i) #Produces a vector [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
end

Q = Chain(Dense(3, 64, relu), Dense(64, 32, relu), Dense(32, 16, relu), 
    Dense(16, 1, identity)) #Creates a neural network. Exact parameters aren't important.
θ, re = Flux.destructure(Q)

f(x) = -re(θ)(x)[1]

gs = gradient(f, myvector)[1] #Takes the gradient of f at the point u.
```

The code creates a vector `myvector` and a neural network `Q`. It then feeds the neural network `myvector` and tries to take the gradient. There is a mutating arrays error:

> Mutating arrays is not supported -- called setindex!(Vector{Any}, ...)
> This error occurs when you ask Zygote to differentiate operations that change
> the elements of arrays in place (e.g. setting values with x .= ...)

Why is there such an error? Nothing seems to be changing the elements of the array. How can I fix this error?

If instead of using `!push` to define the vector I had simply defined `myvector = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]`, then there is no error. However, I don't see why - the `!push` doesn't modify the elements, it just increases the length of `myvector`. For my use case as well, the elements of the vector are complicated and need to be calculated individually, so I can't just define `myvector` as in this MWE.

There is also no error if I define `myvector = AbstractFloat[]`. However, this seems to cause issues elsewhere in my use case (which I will ask about separately if making `myvector` an AbstractFloat is the best solution).

Comment: This might be a bug, can you open an issue... on Zygote probably? Simpler example is just `mat = rand(2,2); gradient(x -> sum(mat * x), Any[1, 2])`. Notice that the stacktrace has `∂(generic_matvecmul!)))(Δ`, so it's differentiating the implementation of matrix multiplication, which internally mutates, instead of using a rule for `*`.

Comment: And, for actual use you certainly want vectors of numbers to have a concrete eltype like Float32. Even when they work, abstractly typed containers will be slow.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is related to your variable, `myvector`. You made a `Vector{Any}`, which is not supported by Zygote. You could make a `Vector{Float64}` like this: `myvector=[0.1 * i for i in 1:3]`. In most cases, `Float32` is needed for machine learning, `myvector=[0.1 * i for i in 1:3].|>Float32`

If you really want to use `push!()`, I would suggest using `myvector = Float64[]` instead of `myvector  = AbstractFloat[]`.